# Is it possible to add a class using javascript? no id and class in the div

Tags: javascript, html, class, addition

[image]

See the attached image, I would like to add a class where the arrow is pointing.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the div elements with

```
getElementsByTagName('div')
```

Then you can add it to the second element by adding the new class to the element at *indice 1*

```
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].classList.add('foo');
```

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1].classList.add('foo');
```

```css
.foo {
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>HI
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The getElementsByTagName() method returns a collection of all elements in the document with the specified tag name (don't forget to check the length so you won't get a null exception)

```
const divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
if (divs.length > 1){
    divs[1].classList.add('your-class');
}
```